# DC.js how to add multi yAxis (not rightYAxis)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

How I can add a few y axis in chart based on dc.js on left side?
[image: something like this]

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you have tried, what errors you are receiving? You may want to review the documentation that comes with the library. You may also want to include the image in the post so that people don't have to follow links

Comment: There may be a way to hack it, but it’s definitely not built in, and more than two might not be possible at all given the current code. May I ask why you want this?